# Python zipfile - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory : zip_file

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

[pyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/)

I need to create a ZIP file and save this file as binary in the database. I used reference from above website. My code is as below:

```
import time
import zipfile
import base64
zip_file = 'some_file_name.zip'
xml_file = 'xml_file.xml'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, mode='w',)
try:
   info = zipfile.ZipInfo(xml_file, 
                                   date_time=time.localtime(time.time()),
                                   )
   info.compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
   info.comment='Remarks go here'
   info.create_system=0
   zf.writestr(info, "<Some XML string>")
finally:
   zf.close()
out = base64.encodestring(zf) # I need to convert zip into binary data in order to update this into database using ORM methods.
```

I don't need to read/write this zip file on File system. I just need to create it programmatically and convert it into binary.

I'm getting this error on the line :  zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, mode='w',)
Error traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
   self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'some_file_name.zip'
```

Sorry for my bad indentation. Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it seems like you are trying to read a file that doesn't exist. Please: 1) fix the code in the question (the indentation is messed up) 2) Provide a *complete* code (what's `invoice_name`?) 3) Provide the *full* error message with traceback so that we can understand which call is causing it.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: if you got `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file_name.zip` error : 1- You not define filename , 2-You haven't permission on currient work directory.

Comment: Try adding an `close(open(zip_file, 'wb'))` and check if that works. If it doesn't you most likely got file system access problems. If the zipped data isn't too large, just replace the file with `StringIO`. Also: `ZipFile`'s are context managers, so try to use `with`.

Comment: If the error is on the 6th line of the example, you don't need to show us the rest of the code

Comment: "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" can also be applicable for **invalid path** (i.e) path that may not exist (some directories may not exist). **Check your entire path.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the file `some_file_name.zip` yet, so it cannot find it. Instead, try using `zip_file = StringIO.StringIO()` and then save the filename later on. I am not sure how to do that, because I am not sure what you want to do with the file. But I guess there is a way to define the filename when you save it on disk or database.